# SetSkip method in MongoDB driver C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

What is an alternative for ***SetSkip*** method in MongoDB driver 2.17 in C#. Before it was used for pagination and old code was like:

```
GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey)
                .Find(query)
                .SetSkip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                .SetLimit(pageSize)
                .SetSortOrder(sort)
                .AsQueryable();
```

I don't know how to rewrite this in new version as this method is now part of MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.

Comment: Can you use `Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)` or does this something different?

Comment: @Markus yes. It helped. With your help I saw now that at some methods they just remove this Set from its name. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `SetSkip`, you can use `Skip` and so on:

```
GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey)
            .Find(query)
            .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
            .Limit(pageSize)
            .SortOrder(sort)
            .AsQueryable();
```